# Expected expression visual studio warning in javascript and razor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, razor, warnings

What is visual studio complaining about here? [image]

Code

```
    PoolsGrid = Ext.extend(SearchableGrid, {
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        var config = {
            url: @(Url.ParameterlessRelativeTemplate<PoolsController>(x => x.List(null)))
        }
    }
});
```

More code:

```
    public static IHtmlString ParameterlessRelativeTemplate<TController>(this UrlHelper url,
                                                                          Expression<Action<TController>> action)
        where TController : Controller
    {
        return RelativeTemplate(url, action, true);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of the `ParameterlessRelativeTemplate<TController>` extension method?

Comment: added ParameterlessRelativeTemplate<TController> method

Comment: I've found that wrapping the 'offending' code in a javascript function makes the warning go away. For example:

    var options = { id: @{ @Model } };

... will generate the false positive error message, whereas this:

    var options = { id: parseInt(@Model) };

... will not. It's a hack admittedly, but it does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks fine. Ignore the error and run your application (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>). It should work fine. Visual Studio Intellisense in Razor views is far from perfect. Hopefully they will improve it in future versions.

Comment: I know that it works, but thought that there is a workaround or something to fix this warning

Comment: No, sorry I am not aware of any fix. It's been a long time since I have completely stopped trusting Visual Studio syntax highlighting and Intellisense in Razor views. I trust the code I write not what some buggy automated tool is telling me.